# Diophantine overconstrained $\big|a\,f\,(g+d\,h)-b\,h\,(e+c\,f)\big|<m$ with unknowns $a,b,c,d$.

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have reduced a cryptanalysis problem to solving for unknowns $a,b,c,d$ the Diophantine inequality $\big|a\,f\,(g+d\,h)-b\,h\,(e+c\,f)\big|<m$ with $0<c<a<m$, $0<d<b<m$.

Addition: If that helps, the context also insures $\big|a\,d-b\,c\big|<m$.

The integers $e,f,g,h,m$ are givens, with $0<e<f\,$, $0<g<h\,$, $\gcd(e,f)=1\,$, $\gcd(g,h)=1\,$, $f\approx m^3\,$, $h\approx m^3\,$. These givens are such that there is a solution, and I vaguely conjecture the later two conditions make it unlikely there are many others.

For the motivating problem, see this [paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm), and my [refutation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/86673/555), that I try to extend. For an example problem (with numerical solution, matching section 5 of the paper and assuming the $x$ is unknown to the cryptanalyst), see this [Mathematica code](https://tio.run/##xVRLT9tAEL77V0wvkIAh@/YukFYtiN6qqlfLoLW9fgDxRo4DCojfns4GaAI99VQpSuaVb75vdmdndmjczA5tYdfr0QHU7b3rFnAwjhxMQUnOqUw4EyZhWmoZPoIxRVSieVRhCVUmoQmjmKWKM00I0yLRkidKSiKielMjCdVGcSWUFkQq9BgTnAgulKFRgzVMMUYTxY1CQCOETBQljFKaJEJJFs0CDrmiJIqQZtG44hYK35Xt0Hok7Lsd6j/7thtSAmfgYG8Pv86gCsb384vUxVBlMEWwEKngM8yu@ISSF@8Me4RAtoNRh1SNRvOGUcfQbDGadxjNDkZg2vgHKD08OKjargQLORRQwpfA06ImoxXFseHwojxM3FBuJBOouAiu5pJLHLiMSnRFYhjXSgm9MwU8QFj4u2UYxFb913yRWlQ0quEQ@zVjOMLWDYwc@gVU4wyJznZ1FoF@gYYNhv2YLkO0RCMPRv6SDiw8Eui3DN4UvupLUI7BQ6Vso0/iRRFKcG7@QZ8dPjb5HzLzwbbdZto29/cOXFzFddxA1fsZ2P0Y8n3wFSxcsaEoAaubYZgvTiaT0rfHvq/xjhyjdDIp@tV88HVv581KEEoIkUFTUaWr6xgerzM4mQJ8u/PFbfrUxnDzHMOl79M2bEEMv/yyK9PRDXqX2P3cd0PbLV152dtN8/TvyGryGEObZWN4zODTFFYxHB622SncZKeRJYiEzbkWRnBlJEVSGldeMROWWjIjE22opFyjoaTCjEwknpSkeGMZx52Ow34qmkX5Kxr@mTOiiCQc15iEZ4Jow/DF0MwIKQxJJNFKUIXnj68Mvi74K4VgnNE/aC6g/VjOXG8HnIAlyLkKsQvX@VnbbaP1@8o8xJqPlSH6etxPjsQViWsSN@Q5O12v10fzkPgN) (updated to also illustrate the following).

---

Update: I made some progress.

- Let $r=a\,f\,(g+d\,h)-b\,h\,(e+c\,f)$. Taking this $\bmod h$ and $\bmod f$ it comes $r\equiv a\,f\,g\bmod h$ and $r\equiv b\,h\,e\bmod f$.
- Compute the integers
  $$\begin{array}{}
  \ell=\gcd(f,h)&&m'=\lceil m/\ell\rceil\\
  f'=f/\ell&&h'=h/\ell\\
  e'=(h'\,e)^{-1}\bmod f'&&g'=(d'\,g)^{-1}\bmod h'
  \end{array}$$
  and define $s=r/\ell$, which is bound to be an integer.
- We have reduced the systems to a single unknown integer $s$ with
  $$
  \begin{align}
  (g'\,s\bmod h')&<m\\
  (e'\,s\bmod f')&<m\\
  0<\big|s\big|&<m'
  \end{align}
  $$
  where the four $e'$, $f'$, $g'$, $h'$ are large known integers (like 30 decimal digits), and the other quantities and the unknown $s$ are much smaller (10 digits).

I think this can be solved efficiently (in time polynomial to the $\log$ of the parameters), perhaps with the [Lenstra–Lenstra–Lovász lattice basis reduction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm), but I still fail.

---

Update: When asked nicely, Mathematica can tackle the above system. [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##XVJda9tAEHzXr9i@BCc94buTdJIbuzRNaSkkEPCjcIo@7iQRfbSW7BCMf7u7e3JrtcaYuZ31aGZ0TTKUukmGKktOp9kNFNVetz3cXDsaVqACzxNB6El/EcooiAL6@lIqrsLIcwyuCLUIRSgFskJ5MuJcRn4YBV6ogoD7TmF3Ai6ihfKUryKfBwpPUvoe9z1fLYRT4o5UUopQeQuFggvfD0IluBRChKGvAuk0pMOfBXcctJmVOnuBrGvzaqg6NNy1E@tP26odYg5L0HB1hT9LMAS@3X@JNQOzgRWK0cTAR2ievbng42mJz6DBZqJREFUgKP9oFAzKi0b5j0Y50SCnud6irxx@7ZJ2QLPaOqwxDSkZUrp1Gkp3r6u6aou4mdc4MlSumde3Tkn1lIQKKvOpe9Xbxy6PCzD4d1egBGloPSVdjdORNQZZsmKqNgd83VBX/QBr6Az0Xb0bC7S21ijxkCA5/wRfq@0I1l2917ED@LF1FLjrwg71bTGT4xIaHP3dREdE7dGBfQ2T42TTxfBLZHCjh3cr4CPCjYbBoWewY7A/MvjeDrrQ2/4cpi@7VxvmEiHp4ZCwlB0on9sZ90IdMpYfjxTx8Q3zxP2PDXxYwee6y17iQ4KxbaOYxbbJID2PyLSt8MjQLcpDyqztsRW4S/s4wYszK@A95FBeY8IUL8FM4zkDc735v5WM8mUIEgLJmbZUTiBHkBJIiRofhvYhn3aA0@PGWevhbhi2VbobdB/bZAweMHyS1hp7GrOuN6fTyf1J9/k3)

I leave the question open in hope someone shows me how to mathematically solve the later system in time polynomial to the $\log$ of the parameters.